# Python - High order function - make_fair_dice

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am working on a project. I need to create dice. And I have a solution below:

```
from random import randint

def make_fair_dice(sides):
    """Return a die that returns 1 to SIDES with equal chance."""
    assert type(sides) == int and sides >= 1, 'Illegal value for sides'
    def dice():
        return randint(1,sides)
    return dice

four_sided = make_fair_dice(4)
six_sided = make_fair_dice(6)
```

I don't understand why the solution created a inner function dice(). I think it's not necessary. But I knew I probably missed a important concept. As always code is not hard but concept.

Comment: Yes, seems unnecessary to me too. Here `dice()` doesn't do anything useful. Also `assert` statement is normally only used in development code, not in final product.

Comment: Not quite sure why the question is tagged with `oop`.

Comment: I have removed the oop. Thanks!

Comment: This is sort of a flavor of OOP -- the higher order function `make_fair_dice` is basically working like a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that your "die" is a function.  If you do:

```
four_sided = make_fair_dice(4)
six_sided = make_fair_dice(6)
```

you're creating a four-sided die and a six-sided die.  You "roll" it by calling the function; you don't need to provide the number of sides again, because the "die" (the function returned by your `make_fair_dice` function) already contains that information.

For example, you can do:

```
print(f"5d4: {sum(four_sided() for _ in range(5))}")
print(f"3d6: {sum(six_sided() for _ in range(3))}")
```

Another way of representing the same concept would be to make your dice objects that contain the number of sides and have a method to roll them:

```
class FairDie:
    def __init__(self, sides: int) -> None:
        assert type(sides) == int and sides >= 1, 'Illegal value for sides'
        self._sides = sides

    def roll(self) -> int:
        return randint(1, self._sides)
```

and then:

```
four_sided = FairDie(4)
six_sided = FairDie(6)
   
print(f"5d4: {sum(four_sided.roll() for _ in range(5))}")
print(f"3d6: {sum(six_sided.roll() for _ in range(3))}")
```